# Echoed div id working in Safari, but not Firefox, Chrome or Opera

Tags: css, image, html, safari, echo

```
echo '<div id="header1"></div>';

#header1 {
    background: url(_images/header1.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px;
```

The background image is appearing in Safari but not any of the other browsers. Does anyone have any idea why this is and how I can solve it?

Comment: Can you post your complete HTML and CSS output (that's not a PHP problem)? Or a jsfiddle or a link?

Answer (score 0):

From the above snippet i am just guessing that you have missed closing barcket `}` but i am not saying its a perfect answer hope so that you have missed to write here or it can be a cause

```
echo '<div id="header1"></div>';

#header1 {
background: url(_images/header1.png);
width: 100%;
height: 240px;
}
```